# probability formula in secretary problem

Tags: probability

I am reading paper about secretary problem http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037722170200601X

here is the definition of problem

1. The number of applicants for employment, n, is finite and known.
2. A single position is available.
3. The n applicants are interviewed (evaluated) sequentially in random order with each of the n! orderings equally likely.
4. The DM can rank order all applicants from best=1 to worst=n without ties.
5. Only the relative ranks of the applicants are made known to the DM, rather than a numeric measure of utility.
6. Once rejected, an applicant cannot be recalled.
7. The DM’s goal is to maximize expected payoff: 1 if the best applicant is selected and 0, otherwise.

An applicant who is the best observed so far is called a candidate

now in section 3 the decision rule is defined as :
"Consider the decision rule: Ignore the first r−1 applicants and choose the first candidate to appear thereafter. This rule is defined for each r=1 to n"

Define $W_n(r)=P(success)$ as the probability of selecting the rank 1 candidate by following the rule with a given fixed r. Then, an equation for $W_n(r)$ can be written by conditioning upon whether the rth applicant is a candidate:
$$ W_n(r) = \frac{1}{r} \frac{r}{n} + ( 1 - \frac{1}{r} ) W_n(r+1) $$
with terminal condition $W_n(n+1)=0$ , this formula is explained as follows

"The probability is 1/r that applicant r is a candidate and the conditional probability is r/n that a candidate at position r is the overall best. On the other hand, if we do not observe a candidate at position r, we move to applicant r+1. From that point we proceed in the same manner which means that we are using the same type of stopping rule but now ignoring the first r+1 applicants"

---

I dont understand how this formula is derived , where from comes $( 1 - \frac{1}{r} ) W_n(r+1)$ ? I guess forumla is $P(A \cup B )$ where A is rth is a candidate and overalbest.

---

PS I dont know how to enumerate :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W_n(r)$ is calculated as the sum of winning probabilities in the two cases where the $r$-th applicant is or isn't a candidate.

With probability $\frac1r$, the $r$-th applicant is a candidate. In this case we select her. Under the condition that the $r$-th applicant is a candidate, the probability that she is the overall best, and thus the winning probability, is $\frac rn$. That yields the first term.

With probability $1-\frac1r$, the $r$-th applicant is not a candidate. In this case we don't select her and move on to the next applicant. At this point the winning probability is the same as if we'd applied the decision rule for $W_n(r+1)$ to begin with, so under the condition that the $r$-th applicant is not a candidate, the winning probability is $W_n(r+1)$. That yields the second term.